# Weird jQuery/Laravel 5.1 REQUEST Behavior

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I'm experiencing a very strange issue. My route is set to `POST`, my jQuery ajax request is set to `POST`, the browser is saying it's sending a `POST`, yet the controller is telling me it's receiving via `GET`.

Here's my route; because I was receiving `methodNotAllowed` errors I've changed it to `REQUEST` for testing - just so I could see what is going on.

```
Route::request('ajax/team-comments',   'UserWalkController@addTeamComments');
```

**Errors I was receiving with the route set to post**

```
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 206
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
```

---

**This is from the browser's Network tab after clicking the submit button...**

[image: Browser result]

---

**In my controller I'm using dd() to see what's happening**

```
public function addTeamComments(Request $request)
{
    dd($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
```

which then spits out

```
"GET"
```

---

**Here's my ajax...**

I'm using jQuery 1.10.2

```
$('.btn-team-comments').on('click',function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var id      = $(this).data('id');
    var token   = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    var comment = $('#comment-' + id).val();

    $.ajax({
        method   : 'POST',
        url      : '/ajax/team-comments',
        cache    : false,
        data     : {
                    'id'      : id,
                    'comment' : comment,
                    '_token'  : token
                   },
        contentType  : false,
        processData  : false,
        headers      : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        dataType : 'json',
        success  : function(response) {

            if(response.type == 'success') {
                // doing stuff here...
            } else {
                alert('Oops');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I should note that I'm not using a `<form>`, I'm just grabbing the contents of a textarea and sending that

```
<div id="formcomment<?php echo $goal_id ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment-<?php echo $goal_id ?>" class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Add Your Comment..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-team-comments" id="btn-team-comments-<?php echo $goal_id ?>" data-id="<?php echo $goal_id ?>"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
</div>
```

Any thoughts as to what is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: What happens if you change it to `Route::post('ajax/team-comments',   'UserWalkController@addTeamComments');`?

Comment: I receive the `methodNotAllowed ` errors I mentioned earlier :)

Comment: Could it possibly be due to needing a csrf token?  Or do you have any other routes hitting `ajax/team-comments`?  You could try changing the route to another name like `ajax/team-comments-test`... just spit-balling ideas. Not really sure if any of it will make a difference or not.

Comment: Yeah, i've tried changing the name just incase, as well as reordering the routes - no dice. And there is a CSRF token in the ajax.

Comment: Anything crazy going on in .htaccess files?

Comment: Do you have the routes cached by chance?

Comment: Also, can you verify that you are using jQuery 1.10.2 by executing this `$.fn.jquery` in browser's console ?

Comment: And in line with @xkcd149's comment: are you using a proxy?

Comment: @Vikas I have cleared the cache (`php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan cache:clear`) several times with no change. is there another one I can try? Here's output from console: `$.fn.jquery: "1.10.2" = $1`

Comment: @Kryten I am on a local env using MAMP.

Comment: Try this: `php artisan route:clear`. Also, can you share your complete routes.php file, at least upto the route which is causing issues

Comment: @Vikas Tried `php artisan route:clear` and have placed the route at the very top of `Routes.php` with no change, then tried clearing the route cache again with no change. `Route::resource('ajax/team-comments',   'UserWalkController@addTeamComments');`

Comment: Your route should be `Route::post('ajax/team-comments', 'UserWalkController@addTeamComments');` , not `Route::resource('ajax/team-comments', 'UserWalkController@addTeamComments');`

Comment: @Vikas it originally was but I changed it from `post` to `resource` to see what was going on because of all the errors. I covered that in my OP. :)

Comment: Ok, after clearing the route cache, have you checked using Route::post?

Comment: @Vikas yes. Same problem: `RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 206`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100179/discussion-between-vikas-and-timgavin).